# Magento 2 Installation fails at 27%

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have this exception when running the installation for Magento 2. Couldn't find further information on how to fix this anywhere, error thrown was not very clear either. Anyone has any ideas? This happens after it says 'Running schema recurring...'

```
Module 'Magento_Amqp':
[ERROR] LogicException: Request schema definition for topic "shared.catalog.product.price.updated" should reference existing service class. Given "Magento\AsynchronousOperations\Api\Data\OperationInterface" in /var/www/tpb.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Communication/Config/Validator.php:71
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/tpb.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Communication/Config/Reader/XmlReader/Converter.php(204): Magento\Framework\Communication\Config\Validator->validateRequestSchemaType('Magento\\Asynchr...', 'shared.catalog....')
#1 /var/www/tpb.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Communication/Config/Reader/XmlReader/Converter.php(111): Magento\Framework\Communication\Config\Reader\XmlReader\Converter->extractTopicRequestSchema(Object(DOMElement))
#2 /var/www/tpb.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Communication/Config/Reader/XmlReader/Converter.php(84): Magento\Framework\Communication\Config\Reader\XmlReader\Converter->extractTopics(Object(DOMDocument))
#3 /var/www/tpb.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php(171): Magento\Framework\Communication\Config\Reader\XmlReader\Converter->convert(Object(DOMDocument))
...
```